# Alamofire unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional, yet I can see the JSON

Tags: json, swift, http, alamofire

Using AlamoFire I can make an API call to my endpoint, it works and connects as expected. Using the print tools I can print the JSON response to the console and see the JSON string, but I am unable to get this string to move to the next function.

I keep getting the error:

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"
```

My code looks like this:

```
func getDataForUser(Username:String, UserToken:String) {
    print("Getting data for user \(Username)")
    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL+userdataURL, parameters: ["Username": Username, "UserToken": UserToken]).response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
        let jSONResponse: NSDictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
        print(jSONResponse)
        if(jSONResponse["Success"] as! Bool == true) {
            print("Success! API Request Worked")
            self.delegate!.didReceiveAPIResults(jSONResponse)
        }
    } 
}
```

The error is on line:

```
self.delegate!.didReceiveAPIResults(jSONResponse)
```

The console looks like this:

```
jSONResponse    NSDictionary    2 key/value pairs   0x78e8d6a0
[0] (null)  "Success" : "1" 
[1] (null)  "Response" : 2 key/value pairs
```

The debug screen for jSONResponse gives me data that I can drill into so I know its not nil.
Where is the nil coming from and how do I resolve?

Comment: Which line is it crashing at?

Comment: self.delegate!.didReceiveAPIResults(jSONResponse)

Comment: Well then it's simple: your delegate is nil.

Comment: So what does that mean? I thought the delegate was being populated by the jSONResponse ?

Comment: @EricD thats what I'm thinking. What class is conforming to the delegate? Can you show us where that happens?

Comment: @MathewJenkinson *Your `self.delegate` optional is nil*. We're not talking about JSON here. You have to check why this delegate is not set and to fix it. It's an optional and you force unwrap it: it crashes, as expected, by design.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, `"1"` is not equal to a `Bool` value of `true`.

It's crashing at `jSONResponse["Success"] as! Bool == true`. You could change this to `jSONResponse["Success"] as! String == "1"`.

If you are able to modify the source of the API you're consuming, you're probably better of making `Success` a `true/false` JSON bool value, and leaving your Swift code as is.

Comment: Its irrelevant, even if the code is just : print(jSONResponse)
self.delegate!.didReceiveAPIResults(jSONResponse) it still fails on self.delegate!.didReceiveAPIResults(jSONResponse)

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. That points to `delegate` being `nil` doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts were that the JSON handler or API Controller were wrong. 
What I had not passed was the delegate variable in the view controller setup. 
EG:

`api.delegate = self`

Thank you to @paulvs and Eric D for pointing that out.